# Newman-Pearson when mean is not equal to zero

Tags: probability

I've this problema.

I found a detector (T) by using Likelihood ratio (two variances, normal distribution).

$(x-\mu)^{2} = \gamma'$

I've seen that in the case of two variances:

$P_{FA} = Pr\{|x|>\sqrt\gamma'|Ho\} = 2Pr\{x>\sqrt\gamma'|Ho\}$
and then:
$P_{FA} = 2Q(\sqrt\gamma'/\sigma_0)$... and $\mu$??

What happen if $\mu$ is not equal zero?

[Update]

I think that:

$P_{FA} = 2Q((\sqrt\gamma'-\mu))/\sigma_0) $;
$P_D = 2Q((\sqrt\gamma'-\mu))/\sigma_1)$

But i'm not sure

regards

Comment: Including your own thoughts and also explicit exposition regarding your variables and formulae, as well as carefully proofreading, well greatly increase your chances of getting effective help. However, your TeX is great. Thanks for that!

Comment: First off, Neyman-Pearson. Second off, you can easily convert the testing problem of testing between two Gaussians (with known parameters) to the case where the null has zero mean by simply subtracting the mean from the data and then testing zero mean vs difference of means. Write down the likelihood ratio, and compare it to a threshold.

Comment: $P_{FA} = 2Q((\gamma'-\mu)/\sigma_0) $; $P_D = 2Q((\gamma'-\mu)/\sigma_1)$ ??

Comment: $P_{FA} = 2Q((\sqrt\gamma'-\mu)/\sigma_0) $;
$\gamma$
$P_D = 2Q(\sqrt\gamma'-\mu)/\sigma_1)$